# BlackBerry layout: HorizontalFieldMahager with 3 items (Including an EditField)

Tags: user-interface, blackberry, horizontalfieldmanager

I'm having a hard time working with the BlackBerry UI API.

What I want to do is creating a "list item" based on a HorizontalFieldManager that consists of the following childFields:

- An optional BitmapField (Horizontal-Left, Vertical-Center)
- A LabelField (Horizontal-left, Vertical-Center)
- A rounded rectangle that contains an single line EditField. The rounded rectangle has a fixed width and height, so the EditField should scroll horizontally inside the rounded rectangle when the text becomes wider than the rounded-rectangle's width.

I've added a image illustrating the desired situation below:

[image: The desired situation...]

Can someone help me with this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The problem is that everytime I'm using a text inputfield (e.g. EditField), the layout completely gets screwed up.
I could post the code here, but that would impose two problems:
Since i'm writing a custom UI-toolkit, I'm having three or more parentclasses with part of the functionality, which makes it difficult to narrow down to the desired behaviour I would like to have.
Second, I would like to have the simplest possible solution, without the pollution of complex class-hierarchy...that's the only way I can understand what I'm doing wrong..